# How to differentiate mentions in a textarea with same name?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am creating a chat application. Till now I have used textarea to send messages. But I want to implement "@mention" functionality in the application. But the problem is that how to key track of mentions with the same name. I show mentions as "@".

I know I can use `div` contenteditable to solve this problem but, if I do that I have to change all my methods that deal with textarea.

I have unique Id for each user but in textarea I can only display user full name.

Is there any way so that I can keep track of my mentions without showing users any ID or something.

P.S. - I add mention when a user click or press enter on a drop down list with user full names

Comment: since you are using drop down list, adding you can take care by having an array to track which elements you have added. But the problem comes when you delete the identical names.

Comment: @Bharadwaj that's what real problem is. i tried using mention start position and end position to manage where each mention is in the text but it turns out to very tedious.

Comment: You can use codes like nickname, which you can make unique. That's the only way I guess.

Comment: @Bharadwaj I can't use a nickname or unique username.